# How to change img srs attr on hover in WordPress with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have following code.
This code is from my theme-options.php file.

and I am still working on it and I develop this all.

```
function social_icons() { 

    $icons = array (
        'facebook'=>__('Facebook','responsivetheme'),
        'google'=>__('Google','responsivetheme'),
        'instagram'=>__('Instagram','responsivetheme'),
        'linkedin'=>__('Linkedin','responsivetheme'),
        'pinterest'=>__('Pinterest','responsivetheme'),
        'rss'=>__('RSS','responsivetheme'),
        'stumbleupon'=>__('Stumbleupon','responsivetheme'),
        'twitter'=>__('Twitter','responsivetheme'),
        'vimeo'=>__('Vimeo',''),
        'youtube'=>__('Youtube','responsivetheme')
        );
    $iconsHover = array (
        'facebook-h'=>__('Facebook','responsivetheme'),
        'google-blank-h'=>__('Google','responsivetheme'),
        'instagram-blank-h'=>__('Instagram','responsivetheme'),
        'linkedin-blank-h'=>__('Linkedin','responsivetheme'),
        'pinterest-h'=>__('Pinterest','responsivetheme'),
        'rss-h'=>__('RSS','responsivetheme'),
        'stumbleupon-blank-h'=>__('Stumbleupon','responsivetheme'),
        'twitter-h'=>__('Twitter','responsivetheme'),
        'vimeo-blank-h'=>__('Vimeo',''),
        'youtube-h'=>__('Youtube','responsivetheme')
        );

    ?>
    <?php
    $theme_options = get_option('new_theme_options',false);
    $theme_values = unserialize($theme_options); 

    $icons_options = get_option('social_settings_responsivetheme_options');
    $icons_values = unserialize($icons_options);
    ?>

    <?php 
    foreach( $icons as $key => $value )  :
    if (!empty ($theme_values[$key])) :
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $theme_values[$key];?>" class="<?php echo esc_html( $value )?>"  title="<?php echo esc_html( $value )?>" target="_blank"><img class="" src="<?php echo  template_dir('/icons/'.esc_attr( $key ).'.png');?>" alt="<?php echo esc_html( $value )?>"  width="<?php echo $icons_values['width'];?>" height="<?php echo $icons_values['height'];?>"  /></a>
<?php endif;//END !empty ($theme_values) ?>


<?php foreach ($iconsHover as $key2 => $value2 ): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var templateDirectory = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>";
            $('.social_icons .<?php echo  esc_html($value2); ?> img').hover(
                function (){
                    $(this).attr('src', templateDirectory + '/icons/<?php echo esc_attr($key2);    ?>.png');
                },
                function () {
                    $(this).attr('src', templateDirectory + '/icons/<?php echo   esc_attr($key); ?>.png');
                });

                });//END document
    </script>
    <?php   endforeach;//END foreach $iconsHover?>


<?php  endforeach;//END foreach ?>


<?php
}//END social_icons()?>
```

The problem is when I hover on icons the hover `img` works but when on mouse out the normal  `img` should  still remains, it doesn't.
It replaces all imgs to 'youtube-h' .

How to do that?

Comment: While I get what you're trying to do here, it's usually best practice to not mix Javascript and PHP

Comment: But I have to, its my need. :|

Comment: For each value in `$icons`, you're looping over all the values in `$iconsHover`.  You just want to use the value in `$iconsHover` that corresponds to the current `$icons` value.  For example, when you're looking at the `$icons['rss']` icon, you only want to look at `$iconsHover['rss-h']`, not loop them all.  But there doesn't seem to be a rule you can use to work out the `$iconsHover` index from the `$icons` one.  You'll either need to put them in the same array, or have a mapping from one set of keys to the other.

Comment: Can you please give a example from on this?

Comment: 1st loop is working correct and and 2nd is not, Why????

Comment: You don't open/close PHP tags (`<?php ?>`) just *because YES* :/ . . . . . . . **Use it only to swap between PHP and HTML/JS**. Try it and you'll see how the code becomes, suddenly, clear :) . . . . . Also, the line `<?php  endforeach;//END foreach ?>` doesn't do what you think it does. The closing `?>` is dead because of the comment `//`.

Comment: @brasofilo that's not true - PHP will recognise the `?>` - see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php): "The 'one-line' comment styles only comment to the end of the line or the current block of PHP code, whichever comes first."

Comment: @Hobo, thanks for the clarification. As the IDEs syntax highlight always show it grayed out, I assumed it was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry my comment wasn't clear enough.

By putting them in nested loops, you're outputting every possible combination ('facebook', 'facebook-h'), ('facebook', 'google-blank-h'), ('facebook', 'instagram-blank-h')... ('youtube', 'vimeo-blank-h'), ('youtube', 'youtube-h').

What I meant by putting them all in one array was something like this:

```
$icons = array (
    array(
        'off'   => 'facebook',
        'hover' => 'facebook-h',
        'label' =>__('Facebook','responsivetheme')
    ),
    array(
        'off'   => 'google',
        'hover' => 'google-blank-h',
        'label' =>__('Google','responsivetheme')
    ),
    array(
        'off'   => 'instagram',
        'hover' => 'instagram-blank-h',
        'label' =>__('Instagram','responsivetheme')
    ),
    array(
        'off'   => 'linkedin',
        'hover' => 'linkedin-blank-h',
        'label' =>__('Linkedin','responsivetheme')
    ),
    array(
        'off'   => 'pinterest',
        'hover' => 'pinterest-h',
        'label' =>__('Pinterest','responsivetheme')
    ),
    array(
        'off'   => 'rss',
        'hover' => 'rss-h',
        'label' =>__('RSS','responsivetheme')
    ),
    array(
        'off'   => 'stumbleupon',
        'hover' => 'stumbleupon-blank-h',
        'label' =>__('Stumbleupon','responsivetheme')
    ),
    array(
        'off'   => 'twitter',
        'hover' => 'twitter-h',
        'label' =>__('Twitter','responsivetheme')
    ),
    array(
        'off'   => 'vimeo',
        'hover' => 'vimeo-blank-h',
        'label' =>__('Vimeo','responsivetheme')
    ),
    array(
        'off'   => 'youtube',
        'hover' => 'youtube-h',
        'label' =>__('Youtube','responsivetheme')
    )
);
```

Then you only need one loop, something like this:

```
foreach ($icons as $icon) {
}
```

and you can use `$icon['off']`, `$icon['hover']`, and `$icon['label']` as appropriate inside that.

Comment: Wow :D what a great answer and idea ! I really appreciate it :D :).